# kendo-drop-down-list data binding limit

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

We are using kendo drop-down list in our project to show drop-down, but we are facing one problem, i got data from database which contain more than 4000 values in list, but the list can not bind with drop down. It's working fine with less amount of data. Is their limitation of kendo drop-down? blow is my html code which working fine for small amount of data.

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list
                                            k-data-text-field="'Text'"
                                            k-data-value-field="'Value'"
                                            k-option-label="'--Select--'"
                                            k-data-source="companyList"
                                            ng-model="data.Id" k-filter="'contains'"
                                            class="full-width m-b form-control" required></select>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but 4000 values on client side is not good anyway, you should bind, for example, 20 values and turn on server-side filter/search.

Comment: Take a look at this dropdownlist virtualization [demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/virtualization) by Telerik. We use this in our applications for dropdowns with large data.